# indexOf a "/ " in a string

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a HotSpot URL that looks like this:

```
http://192.168.2.251/XPages/Website/wfswebsite.nsf/xpIndex.xsp?page=ccProducts.xsp&product=ccWFAXPages.xsp
```

I'm trying to extract out the 192.168.2.251 from the URL indexOf returns the first occurence of the /. I can't index on the 192 because in real life it could be an IP address or an actual domain name.

Comment: Please show your code and what problem you have with it.

Comment: Are you limited, for some reason, to `indexOf()` or RegExp approaches? There are better ways, but they depend on your constraints and requirements; it *seems* you want to get the domain of a given URL?

Comment: `url.split('/')[2]` should do :-)

Comment: you might want to check out http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/

Comment: What does represent this domain? If it is the domain hosting your app, then `document.location.hostname` is enough, or `document.location.host` in case you need the port. Otherwise, see D. Thomas answer

Comment: There's a url cheatsheet for XPages available here. http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/url.xsp that likely has an example answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions above got me looking for some alternate solutions and in fact this code does exactly what I want:

```
var thisURL = context.getUrl();
var host:String = thisURL.getHost();
```

because thisURL is an xspURL the getHost extracts the 192.168.2.251 in this case and returns exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript?

Comment: Bergi, it's server side javascript. Bill had to clear it up though. But great you found out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption you're able to utilise a function, and aren't limited for any reason to `indexOf()` approach, I'd suggest:

```js
function getDomain(url) {
  // create a temporary <a> element:
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  // set its `href` property (not attribute) to
  // the given URL:
  a.href = url;

  // return the hostname of the created-<a> element:
  return a.hostname;
}

var url = "http://192.168.2.251/XPages/Website/wfswebsite.nsf/xpIndex.xsp?page=ccProducts.xsp&product=ccWFAXPages.xsp",
  hostname = getDomain(url);

document.getElementById('urlString').textContent = url;
document.getElementById('hostname').textContent = hostname;
```

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  max-width: 90%;
}
li::before {
  text-indent: 1em;
  content: attr(id)": ";
  display: block;
  color: #696;
}
li:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="urlString"></li>
  <li id="hostname"></li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`URLUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hostname).